# Sort the pictures and guess the next one

Tags: knowledge, visual

There is a logical relation between these pictures that gather them all together. Can you sort them and guess what picture can be the next one?

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]
[image: 5]
[image: 6]
[image: 7]
[image: 8]

Hope this is an innovative and interesting puzzle.

Spoiler: The next missing person is

> [Betty Binns Fletcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betty_Binns_Fletcher)

Comment: Please don't use logic-puzzle unless formal deduction is involved.

Comment: Is it the people or the pictures we need a relationship between?  In other words, would different pictures of the same people work just as well?

Comment: Answer is no. there is no relation between these people.the relation is related to ɥʇɐǝp ɹᴉǝɥʇ ...

Comment: I update the question with a spoiler

Answer (score 6):

These are all people who

> died in the last 3 years. The proper sort order is the order in which they died.

The names of the people are, starting in the top row working left to right,

> Frank Bank, Leon Bramlett, Ray Hatton, Leon Bibb, Valery Belousov, Lionel Pickens (aka Chinx), Dale Armstrong, and George Francis.

Sorting these by the criterion mentioned above yields

> 1. Frank Bank (April 13, 2013)
>  2. George Francis (October 22, 2014)
>  3. Dale Armstrong (November 28, 2014)
>  4. Ray Hatton (March 4, 2015)
>  5. Valery Belousov (April 16, 2015)
>  6. Lionel Pickens (May 17, 2015)
>  7. Leon Bramlett (October 19, 2015)
>  8. Leon Bibb (October 23, 2015)

Comment: I modify the title,you need to find some sort of logical relation between these people so you may guess the next one. you are in a right track!

Comment: So the sorting is not right. rest is correct

Comment: The sorting could be the count of the days between their last birthday and their death: 1. Frank Bank 1 day, and so on...

Comment: raed the spolier inside the question